# Exchange 2010 to Office 365 Migration

Tags: backup, exchange-2010, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-365

We're looking to migrate all of our mailboxes etc onto Office 365 from Exchange 2010. We aim to still primarily use our local Exchange 2010 setup however, the office 365 setup will act as a 'live backup'. This meaning, if our local exchange 2010 setup were to go down, we could instantly start using the Office 365 setup without any downtime.

So in short, I'm here to ask if it's possible to migrate all of our Exchange 2010 data to Office 365 in the aforementioned fashion while maintaining synchronisation between the two?

Kind regards,

Comment: I almost dread to ask but what problem do you think this is solving? Because if you woke up one morning and thought *our email system just isn't byzantine enough* then just install lotus notes, like everyone else who wants to ruin their professional lives does.

Answer (score 2):

No you cannot do this.  The mailbox has to reside in one or the other in a hybrid environment.

What you are asking is more like trying to use Office 365 as a sort of DAG member with your local Exchange server, which Office 365 doesn't offer.

You could look at hosting a VM with a provider that would allow you to create an Exchange VM to become part of your Exchange Org and be a part of a DAG with your on-premise server if you don't have a separate office already that you could put another Exchange server in.